# Combinations with missings

Tags: c#

so i am new to C# and I've got this task:

I have a list of unidentified number of people(ex. 5 people). The task is to get the groups of people where the person and the person after him in the list can't be in the same group.

EX:
5 people

{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{2,4},{2,5},{3,5},{1,3,5}

I used the combination method from the link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G
and i have this code

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        outputBox.Clear();
        int nr = Convert.ToInt32(nmbrBox.Value);
        double tmp = Math.Pow(2, nr);
        double combs = tmp - 1;
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= nr; i++ )
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }

        outputBox.AppendText(combs.ToString() + " combinari\n\n");

        List<string> allCombinations = new List<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= list.Count; i++)
        {
            var combis = new Facet.Combinatorics.Combinations<int>(list, i, Facet.Combinatorics.GenerateOption.WithoutRepetition);
            allCombinations.AddRange(combis.Select(c => string.Join("", c)));
        }

        foreach (var combi in allCombinations)
        {            
            outputBox.AppendText(combi + "\n");
        }
    }
```

How do i make it show me only the result i want?

Comment: What have you tried? How are you filtering your combinations to determine the legal values?

Comment: I've tried to get the combinations from "allCombinations" so i can use a variable and check wether the number[i+1]=number[i]+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer a straightforward solution. Considering you have your `group` string in format "1 2 3" or "1" or "1 2", foreach group in allCombinations use a validation method like:

```
public static bool IsGroupValid(string group)
{
    var indexes= group.Split(' ').Select(x=>Int32.Parse(x)).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (indexes.Any(x=>x+1==indexes[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So it'd look like that:

```
foreach (var combi in allCombinations)
{        
    if(IsGroupValid(combi))    
        outputBox.AppendText(combi + "\n");
}
```

Comment: 1. Too many paranteses after Parse (just fyi)
2. indexes won't accept Length

Comment: Worked as charm! Thank you! Sorry for being annoying :) Now i know that i have to study lists.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a mix of Windows Forms and some combinatorial code. In my answer I will focus on the combinatorial aspect of your question. The library you are using seems to be very nice but to create a self-contained answer I have decided to create my own method for generating combinations. The implementation is using LINQ and recursion in a way that is not good for performance but as long as you do not have too many elements that should not be a problem.

To create the combinations of a source sequence of a given length the following extension method is used (you have to put this inside a `static class`):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>  Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Int32 count)
  where T : IComparable<T> {
  if (count == 1)
    return source.Select(t => new T[] { t });
  return Combinations(source, count - 1)
    .SelectMany(
      values => source.Where(value => value.CompareTo(values.Last()) > 0),
      (values, value) => values.Concat(new T[] { value })
    );
}
```

If the input is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `count` is 4 then the output is `[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5]`.

To make it easier to determine if a combination is valid another extension method is used to create tuples from a sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> ToTuples<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
  using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator()) {
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
      yield break;
    var lastValue = enumerator.Current;
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
      yield return Tuple.Create(lastValue, enumerator.Current);
      lastValue = enumerator.Current;
    }
  }
}
```

If the input is `[1, 2, 4, 5]` then the output is `[[1, 2], [2, 4], [4, 5]]`.

A predicate is used to determine if given combination is valid. The combination is assumed to be a sequence of indices so two consequtive indices has to be at least 2 a part to be valid:

```
Boolean IsValidCombination(IEnumerable<Int32> combination) {
  return combination
    .ToTuples()
    .All(tuple => tuple.Item2 - tuple.Item1 > 1);
}
```

Now you can put it together. In this case the input is an array of names:

```
var people = new[] { "Arthur", "Bertha", "Cristobal", "Dolly", "Edouard" };
var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, people.Length);
var result = Enumerable
  .Range(1, people.Length - 1)
  .SelectMany(i => indices.Combinations(i))
  .Where(IsValidCombination)
  .Select(combination => combination.Select(i => people[i]));
```

This gives the following result:

```
Arthur
Bertha
Cristobal
Dolly
Edouard
Arthur, Cristobal
Arthur, Dolly
Arthur, Edouard
Bertha, Dolly
Bertha, Edouard
Cristobal, Edouard
Arthur, Cristobal, Edouard
```

Comment: Thanks for this method. I will definately check it out :)
The problem i've got with my method is the fact that it stocks the answers in the string[]. So if i go n = 30, it starts to load my RAM more than 1.5Gb, causing my app to freeze. I have to find a method that shows the result imediately after finding it, so it won't load the memory.

Comment: @CroveanVlad: I am afraid that my approach suffers from performance problems if there are too many elements. However, the combinations are generated on the fly so you might experience that hardly any memory is used at the cost of very high CPU time requirements. With n = 30 you probably need a very specific algorithm to avoid using either excessive memory or CPU.